# Filling in gaps in illustrator (by not using gap detection)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to colour an image on adobe illustrator.
I initially "image traced" the image, so many of the strokes disappeared. I used live paint and direct selection to fill in the colours. However, now I am at the point of finishing my colouring, but there are gaps outside of my image that I can't fill.
I tried gap detection, it does not fill the gaps. I tried joining the strokes with the paths but then I can't colour within the region. How do I join the gaps and colour within it? I hope what I am asking makes sense.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzGeM.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

At some point one often needs to **expand** the artwork and manually correct or alter paths to gain the attain the desired appearance.

`Object > Expand` or `Object > Expand Appearance`

For a Live Paint Group, click the <kbd>Expand</kbd> button on the control bar across the top of the screen.